# Ask a problem of asymptotic solution of a system of nonlinear differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I was struggling with a modeling problem in a game.Many soldiers fight with each other, the number of casualties to the enemy is related to the number of quadratic, then we can make the following differential equation:
$$
x'(t)=-ay(t)^2
$$
$$
y'(t)=-bx(t)^2
$$
a and b are constants

Because of the actual business requirements, I wanted to find an asymptotic analytic solution,please help

Answer (score 3):

The function $V(x,y)=bx^3-ay^3$ is a conserved quantity/first integral of the system:
$$
\dot V= 3bx^2\dot x-3ay^2\dot y=3bx^2(-ay^2)-3ay^2(-bx^2)=0.
$$
It means that the point $(x,y)$ on a plane will stay on the level curve $bx^3-ay^3=C$ during the battle:
[image]

Let the initial values of $x$ and $y$ be $x_0$ and $y_0$. At any moment of the battle
$$
bx^3-ay^3=bx_0^3-ay_0^3,
$$
so if the side $y$ wins, the final values are $x_{final}=0$ and $$y_{final}=\sqrt[3]{\frac{ay_0^3-bx_0^3}{a}},$$ if the side $x$ wins, then $y_{final}=0$ and $$x_{final}=\sqrt[3]{\frac{bx_0^3-ay_0^3}{b}}.$$

Comment: where is "t"??????

Comment: @abraxas If you need $x$ or $y$ as a function of $t$, then I have to disappoint you: there is no analytic solution

Comment: i knew no analytic .So my question is "asymptotic analytic solution"....For example, using perturbation or multi-scale methods

Comment: @abraxas There is nothing to Taylor-expand in the right hand side of your system so the perturbation method would not work.

Comment: @abraxas If you need to plausibly display the course of the battle, it is best to take the appropriate
piece of the curve $V(x,y)=C$ and introduce a parameter

Comment: That means only arithmetic solution?But I couldn't get a result using mathematica

Comment: "the curve and introduce a parameter". How?

Comment: @abraxas I'm not sure if this is a mathematical question :) We are entering the field of game design. You can express, for example, $y$ in terms of $x$: $y=\sqrt[3]{\frac{bx^3-c}{a}}$. Now let $x$ be some function of $t$ and obtain $x=x(t)$, $y=\sqrt[3]{\frac{bx^3(t)-c}{a}}$. $x(t)$ or, maybe, $x(t,a,b)$ should be choosen by trial and error or by using the least squares method - integrating the original system, comparing the results

Comment: alas, only arithmetic solution?But using mathematica cannot get a result,maybe you try it?

Comment: @abraxas If it is, it is expressed through some scary special functions, which are not worth calculating in the game

Comment: alas,The boss thinks this kind of computation formula can better reflect the head count advantage

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100962/discussion-between-avk-and-abraxas).